# Moving items in List<>

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for efficient way to move certain countries in List of countries to top of the List.

```
 List<Countries> {"Italy","Germany","USA","England","Canada","Mexico"}
 //do something
 List<Countries> {"USA","Canada","Mexico","Italy","Germany","England"}
```

so basically I want to move certain countries(USA,Canada and Mexico) to top of list and rest in same order.

List of countries is actually an Object with Id associated with country Name.

Comment: You need to include a criteria in order to sort your lists. Simply having the list of strings isn't going to provide many options for sorting without an external source of data.

Answer (score 3):

Add a field called `SortOrder` to `Country`:

```
public class Country
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can sort your `List<Country>` using LINQ

```
list.OrderBy(country => country.SortOrder);
```

You can leave all other countries as `SortOrder=0` and add negative numbers for those countries you want to pull to the top.

e.g.

```
var countries = new List<Country>();
countries.Add(new Country { CountryName="USA", SortOrder = -1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with Linq, but that won't modify an existing collection. You *could* use Linq to create a new collection with different criteria, but that doesn't seem like what you're asking for here.

Here's one simple solution using the [`Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `List<T>` class:

```
var list = new List<string> {"Italy","Germany","USA","England","Canada","Mexico"};
// Items you want to pull to the front of the list, in reverse order
var toSort = new[] { "Mexico", "Canada", "USA" }; 
// Sort by index in toSort
list.Sort((x , y) => Array.IndexOf(toSort, y) - Array.IndexOf(toSort, x));
```

This will yield:

```
List<string> {"USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Italy", "Germany", "England"};
```

Note: This sample uses `string` values. To use this method with a custom class, you'd have to override the [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) method or tweak the comparison delegate appropriately.

Comment: Love the simplicity of solution but I found this 'listA.Concat(listB.Except(listA)).ToList()' to work for my needs.